# Page gives an error about state information is invalid and can be corrupted

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, jmeter

I am working with jmeter and after recording script when i am running that script then i am getting an error on some of the pages:

```
The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

   [FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.]
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +77
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String     serializedState) +4
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +113
```

Why i am getting this error?

Page on which i am getting error by using jmeter is working perfect when i am opening this manually.

Comment: did you get the solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is to use correlations, since the state information will be generated dynamically.

Please refer to below links for implementation:

- http://apache-jmeter.blogspot.com/2011/12/correlation-regular-expression.html
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j8bBiCeQ88w

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode (Base64) your (anti-forgery) token(s) before posting to server.

...BTW: why not to try first search for answer if not with Google than across this resource or in [Jmeter mailing archive](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/) at least, before asking?
Be sure, you'll find a lot of useful and interesting things!

Comment: Thanks Alies for the suggestion but there is a  different issue,out of  5 thread jmeter is working fine with 1-2 times but for the remaining thread jmeter through the above error.i have tried all the possible way to remove that error but still i am not find the exact reason....

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is two years old, but I had the exact same issue, including the fact that only some of the threads had the error. I fixed it by just checking the "Use multipart/form-data for POST" option in the request that was getting the error.